# Why only first row is showing using Recyclerview gridlayoutmanager

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, kotlin

Adapter Calling:

```
adherenceDetails.hasFixedSize()
                    adherenceDetails.layoutManager= GridLayoutManager(this@PatientPlanStatus,3)
                    adherenceDetails.adapter= PatientPlanDetails(this@PatientPlanStatus, patientPlanAdherenceData.data?.get(0)?.adherence!!)
```

Adapter:

```
class PatientPlanDetails(var mcontext: Context, var patientDatas:ArrayList<AdherencePoJo>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return patientDatas.size
    }

    val TAG="PatientPlanDetails"


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        val v = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.patient_plan_adherence, parent, false)
        return Item(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, position: Int) {

        //Log.i(TAG,"On Bind")
        (holder as Item).bindData(patientDatas.get(position),mcontext)


    }

    class Item(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


        fun bindData(patienData: AdherencePoJo, context: Context) {

            val TAG="PatientPlanDetails"

        }

    }


}
```

getItemCount() returning the correct size. But only first row is showing. Please check the image [image]
Card has actual height but the item inside it are not visible.
I am getting no log in the logout also.

Comment: Please share your xml code.

Comment: It is because you have provide the recycle view height as match_parent which should be wrap_content or try with some fixed value like 100dp if wrap_content won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your **patient_plan_adherence** layout height as wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Try with this property in your RecyclerView:

> app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

[image]